# Flutter - Firebase iOS App: Build error: Module 'firebase_core' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, module

I'm making a Flutter App with Firebase as the backend (I have setup both connections from Android and iOS to Firebase already).
I can build and run my app on both Android Emulator and real Android device, no problem.
But when I try to run my app on an iOS Simulator (haven't tried real iPhone yet), **build fails in the file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h` with this error: `Module 'firebase_core' not found`.**

Content of the file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h`:
(if I comment out the line `@import cloud_firestore;`, it will just throw the same error at the next such @import)

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// clang-format off

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>)
#import <cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>
#else
@import cloud_firestore;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_auth/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_auth/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_auth;
#endif

#if __has_include(<firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_core;
#endif

#if __has_include(<flutter_tts/FlutterTtsPlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_tts/FlutterTtsPlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_tts;
#endif

#if __has_include(<shared_preferences_ios/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>)
#import <shared_preferences_ios/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>
#else
@import shared_preferences_ios;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseCorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseCorePlugin"]];
  [FlutterTtsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterTtsPlugin"]];
  [FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

I recently opened this flutter project for the first time in months, so I had to update a lot of things. I have updated all dependencies in pubspec.yaml, upgraded from Flutter 2.?.? to Flutter 3.3.8 etc.
One important thing to mention is that Firebase now suggests you to add the dependencies to the iOS app via the Swift Package Manager (SPM), instead of pasting code into your Podfile. May this be the source of the problem?

This is the content of my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore //firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    FirebaseApp.configure() //firebase
      
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I don't know what other information to add to help you understand where the problem might be. If you think I should add something, please tell me.

Comment: UPDATE: So I deleted the whole ios folder and ran "flutter create -i swift -a kotlin --org <my domain> <my app name>" again (this didn't affect the android folder), and instead of using the Swift Package Manager, I did it the old way with cocoapods, NOW MY APP WORKS AGAIN

Comment: In my case all i have to is adding     "  pod 'Firebase/Core' " in my podfile. 
      flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do

  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end